# Differential Privacy: why $\delta$ negligible on the row numbers?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, data-privacy, negligible, differential-privacy

The definition of differential privacy says that an algorithm  $M$ is $(\epsilon,\delta)$-differentially private if

$$P(M(x \in D) \in S)\leq e^\epsilon P(M(x \in D')\in S) + \delta$$

where $D,D'$ differ by one row and $\delta$ is  $\text{negligible}$ in the number of database rows, so $\delta< \frac{1}{p(n)}$ with $n$ being the number of database rows; why do we take $n$ as parameter for this negligible function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\varepsilon$-differential privacy is *absolute*: for any pair of databases, you cannot gain more than a small amount of probabilistic information about a single individual. When you add or remove an individual in your database, *all possible outputs* of your algorithm can appear with similar probability.

By contrast, $(\varepsilon,\delta)$-differential privacy allows this process to fail sometimes: you can have an output that happens with $\delta>0$ probability if the individual is present, and *never* happens otherwise. If you're super unlucky and this output comes out of your algorithm, an attacker can *know* that the individual in question is in the set.

Now, how often does that happen? How many users in the dataset are at risk? Well, each user has a $\delta$ probability that this might happen to them. So on average, this will happen $\delta \cdot n$ times (expected value of a binomial law of parameters $(n,\delta)$).

You want $\delta \cdot n$ to be small, because you don't want to leave *any* user at risk. If $\delta=\frac{1}{100\cdot n}$, you can say "with 99% probability, this bad scenario doesn't happen". But if delta is not a negligible function in $n$, then on average, your algorithm will leave some users at risk when $n$ grows.

Comment: thanks @Ted, but why "you can have an output that happens with δ
>0 "? isn't output probability P(M(x∈D′)) (for D')?

Comment: Yes, so for a database D', some output $S$ has a small chance $\delta$ of happening, while for another adjacent database D, it can absolutely not happen. So if the attacker observes $S$ and knows that the database is *either* D or D', they can now that it's actually D' and not D, with certainty. They have gained *certainty* on the data even though the process was probabilistic. That can't happen if $\delta=0$.