# Calculating the privacy that Renyi ($\epsilon, \delta$) Differential Privacy satisfies

Tags: data-privacy, database, differential-privacy

I add differential privacy (DP) to my machine learning models by using [PyTorch-DP](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch-dp). PyTorch-DP supplies me with the values: $\epsilon$ and $\delta $. I know that the $\epsilon$ tells us something about the probability $\rho$ that the privacy of individuals in the dataset (DP) is broken. So, a $\rho$ of 0.5 might correspond to an $\epsilon$ of 2 (depending on the statistics that are released).

So now, my question is: With the implementation that PyTorch-DP uses (Renyi DP calculated by using the Moments Accountant method), to what $\rho$ does the $\epsilon$ correspond to? If I do not know this, how can I say something "meaningful" about the level of privacy $\rho$ that $\epsilon$ satisfies?

Comment: This is [cross-posted](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/233664/86735) on Information Security site. Please if you are the same person, delete one copy.

Comment: I don't think your interpretation of $\varepsilon$ is quite right. What do you mean by "the probability $\rho$ that the privacy of individuals in the dataset is broken"? I generally find the [Bayesian interpretation of $\varepsilon$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44739/41989) to be the most accessible. I also don't understand how this question is about Rényi privacy, whose parameters are not $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ but $(\alpha,\varepsilon)$. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your interpretation of $\varepsilon$ in DP is correct. You can find a decent explanation of this parameter in [this crypto.SE question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/intuitive-explanation-of-the-varepsilon-parameter-in-differential-privacy) and links therein.

The best intuition I have for Rényi privacy is that it bounds the *average* of the [privacy loss](https://desfontain.es/privacy/privacy-loss-random-variable.html)) $L(O)$: instead of being a worst-case property, like DP ("for *all* outputs $O$, $L(O)$ is lower than $\varepsilon$"), Rényi privacy is an *average-case* property ("when we average $L(O)$ across all possible outputs $O$, the result is lower than $\varepsilon$"). The $\alpha$ parameter determines which *kind* of average we're using: used: $\alpha=1$ bounds the arithmetic mean of $L(O)$, $\alpha=2$ bounds the arithmetic mean of $e^{L(O)}$, $\alpha=3$ bounds the quadratic mean of $e^L(O)$, etc.